# How to know what WPF control properties I can use in XAML

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml

I'm trying to learn WPF, and of course struggling with XAML.  I'm looking at [the ListBox control](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.listbox%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) which has an `Items` property.  So I start by trying this:

```
<ListBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="213" Margin="75,61,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="218">
    <Items>
        First
        Second
        Third
    </Items>
</ListBox>
```

I get a compiler error:

> Items is not supported in a Windows Presentation Foundation (WPF)
>   project.

I noticed in the above-linked MSDN page that I should instead use this syntax:

```
<ListBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="213" Margin="75,61,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="218">
    <ListBoxItem>First</ListBoxItem>
    <ListBoxItem>Second</ListBoxItem>
    <ListBoxItem>Third</ListBoxItem>
</ListBox>
```

How am I supposed to infer that?  What WPF mechanism says that I must do the latter and cannot even use certain properties (e.g. `Items`)?  The `ListBox` control has an `Items` property according to the docs, so what am I missing?

Secondly, I know from [this MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc700358.aspx) that I can use a data template like this:

```
<ListBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="213" Margin="75,61,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="218">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding XPath=@desc}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

where there is a `TextBlock` that is substituted in for each item in the data source.  However, that would seem to indicate that I'd be forced to formulate the above XAML like this (which *does* work):

```
<ListBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="213" Margin="75,61,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="218">
    <ListBoxItem><TextBlock>First</TextBlock></ListBoxItem>
    <ListBoxItem><TextBlock>Second</TextBlock></ListBoxItem>
    <ListBoxItem><TextBlock>Third</TextBlock></ListBoxItem>
</ListBox>
```

instead of this:

```
<ListBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="213" Margin="75,61,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="218">
    <ListBoxItem>First</ListBoxItem>
    <ListBoxItem>Second</ListBoxItem>
    <ListBoxItem>Third</ListBoxItem>
</ListBox>
```

How does the latter work, and how am I supposed to infer that it works?  Is there a name for that magic behavior?

Comment: I'd love some feedback instead of just down votes.

Comment: Take a look at the [Data Templating Overview](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742521.aspx) article on MSDN.

Comment: Shame on the downvoting trolls. WPF has a steep learning curve but its amazing once everything clicks. Added my upvote.

Comment: @Contango yeah I know it's like people get down voted just for being completely new at something. Down voting for ignorance I guess. I see it all the time and it's frustrating.  Anyway thanks for the support.

Answer (score 1):

The best tip i can give you if you're starting WPF and you want to know which control can go where is that you should develop directly in Visual studio because you'll have the intellisense that will tell you which block can go where.

About your *first* question,
In this case, the "Items" you're talking about is a property, properties cannot be used like this, it can either be used:

```
<ListBox Items="whatever"/>
```

or

```
<ListBox>
    <ListBox.Items>
         Something
    </ListBox.Items>
</ListBox>
```

**But**

Items is not a property that you can really use in xaml, it's simply a property that you can use in the c# code-behind to view what are the items in your listbox.

As for your *second* question,
Every control has a "default" property that you can set without specifying it, for example, a "TextBlock". You can write the text between the opening and closing tags without having to write that you're modifying the Text property.

```
<TextBlock>Test Text</TextBlock>
```

instead of

```
<TextBlock Text="Test Text"/>
```

In your "ListBoxItem" case, the default property is Content. Content will write the text if you're writing text in it, but you could also put more blocks in it to expand it.

```
<ListBox>
    <ListBoxItem>This text will appear</ListBoxItem>
    <ListBoxItem>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
             <TextBlock Text="This text will appear in the middle"/>
             <TextBlock>This Text will appear last</TextBlock>
        </StackPanel>
    </ListBoxItem>
</ListBox>
```

The content property can only hold 1 thing though, so that's why you need to put a "StackPanel"(or any other panel) to hold multiple blocks in it.

If you need more details about listbox, you can go there:
http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/list-controls/listbox-control/

Answer (score 0):

I'd personally recommend subscribing to something like PluralSight or Lynda.

You learn 80% of what you do, but far less of what you read in a book.

Open up Visual Studio, and follow along with the tutorial video, typing into Visual Studio. Pause if the tutor gets ahead of you. You need a lot of foundational knowledge, and this is the perfect way to get it. Hang in there, once everything clicks, WPF is very nice to work with.

Disclaimer: I am not associated with either of those companies.